# Exporting an Android file into a binary file

Tags: android, eclipse, binary

I'm trying to put an Android app in the Amazon app store, and they require a binary file. How do I compile my app into a binary file to upload?

Answer (score 1):

Hey you don't really have to convert the apk into the binary file separately. In the binary tab section you need to upload the apk and has to fill the necessary information. Refer this [link](http://help.yoyogames.com/entries/22897037-Submitting-To-Amazon) for more info